# Windows 7 product key is blocked by activation server

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation, product-key

I bought Windows 7 Ultimate from eBay around 8 months back. I got original Microsoft DVDs (for 32 and 64 bit) product sheet. To verify the genuinness, I activated the windows immediately after installation. It got successfully activated.

After that, I used Microsoft's online genuine windows check and it was also successful. Everything was working fine since last month. Windows updates were regularly taking place. Then one fine day, I got blackground and a message telling me that my Windows is not genuine. I discussed with friends and they suggested to re-install it.

Today I re-installed the windows and tried to activate it. I gor the message

> Your Windows Product Key is blocked by the activation server.

What is the solution for this problem? If my windows were nor genuine, how come it worked properly for around seven months? Shall I contact Microsoft for the same? I don't know where to contact Microsoft.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hate to tell you this, but you were almost certainly scammed. I tell clients never to buy software on eBay as it is just too risky: eBay is rampant with bogus software. You can call Microsoft's activation line, but they will probably confirm this.

Comment: But how come it was working for seven months?

Comment: Because the code had not gotten back to Microsoft as "compromised" at that point. As more and more people tried to use it, their activation databases probably flagged it.

Comment: For more info: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938450

Comment: The link suggest to contact Microsot Activation Call Center. I will call them to find out a solution. I will post their response here. Thanks KCotreau.

Comment: Checked with Microsoft. They told that the product has reached its activation limit. There is no way out of this... I have to buy a new one.