# Cheap Windows 7 - is it a scam?

Tags: windows-7, license

I need to purchase a genuine Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit for several self-made computers. I googled the price and found that in stores like Newegg and Amazon it's never less than $190-200. But I found bunch of site where it costs just $60-70. Download only. They claim it completely legitimate license. I am not going to advertize those site here, you can easily find it.

My question is do you think it's really legitimate? Then what's the trick? Would you buy there?

Sorry if it's a wrong place to ask such question. I don't participate in many forums and I trust you guys.

Comment: The fact that you are asking the question should give you the answer.  Trust your instincts.  BTW, you can download it for free from Digital River (Microsoft's official distributor).  What costs money is the license.  Those sites aren't selling legit licenses.

Comment: @fixer1234 can somebody not resell their license cheap?

Comment: @barlop - Sure.  An individual who purchased an license and never used it could.  Where would he get bulk quantities of such licenses to resell?  There is still a retail market for these, so excess retail stock can be sold at retail.  These sites sell previously used licenses that will fail when Microsoft catches up, or re-manufacturer's licenses in violation of the terms, or similar.

Comment: Unless you get it from MS directly or get it from an OEM with your computer you should get a COA and a disk; if you don't, then its a scam.  See this SU question/answers: [How to check if the software is genuine?](http://superuser.com/questions/305998/how-to-check-if-the-software-is-genuine) Anyhow, this is off-topic for SU (IMO) as it's asking about legalities of a random website's offerings, not an actual computer problem.

Comment: In-fact a retailor is required to provide you that COA by Microsoft to even sell that license.  So the fact you wouldn't get one is not only risky to you as the consumer but they are not even allowed to sell it without it.  Retail copies of Windows 8 come with a COA even through the OEM licenses ( those on OEM machines ) do not, although those keys, are embedded into firmware.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a special re-manufacturers license available.  I get one with each refurbished XP I buy.  They are intended to be installed on refurbished PC's and never sold.  They are "locked" to the one PC, and re-activation may be difficult.

This could be what is being sold. Sometimes they flat out tell you, sometimes not.

In the end, it is a valid license (it will activate) but probably a license violation because of the way you procured it.

Look for the "Windows 7 Pro OA" moniker.

Comment: Are you talking about [this](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/antipiracy/Pages/get_genuine_kit.aspx#fbid=dzMRguTAu9c) because those kits are only valid only installations that are not genuine.  Does not really apply to this user.